# Cannot debug, Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00007c37 (code=-6)

Tags: java, android, debugging, runtime, lang

I ran into the following situation where I cannot debug the android app. I can run it but cannot debug it. I started brand new project copied everything and it worked (meaning was able to debug) but got this again. I tried both on emulator and my phone but no avail. I am using Android Studio 0.5.1

it fails at the very beginning. i don't feel like it has entered MainActivity. The moment app launches, I get "Unfortunately btbnie has stopped working" message.

Appreciate any help/direction...

```
    03-19 21:10:24.334  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? Sending WAIT chunk
    03-19 21:10:24.334  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine W/ActivityThread? Application com.learn.btnine.btbnine is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
    03-19 21:10:25.034  31799-31809/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/art? Debugger is active
    03-19 21:10:25.144  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? Debugger has connected
    03-19 21:10:25.144  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:25.344  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:25.544  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:25.744  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:25.944  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:26.144  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:26.344  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:26.544  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:26.754  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:26.954  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:27.154  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:27.354  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:27.554  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:27.754  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:27.954  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:28.154  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:28.354  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:28.554  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:28.754  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:28.954  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...
    03-19 21:10:29.154  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? waiting for debugger to settle...


    03-19 21:10:29.364  31799-31799/com.learn.btnine.btbnine I/System.out? debugger has settled (1455)
    03-19 21:10:29.504  31799-31809/com.learn.btnine.btbnine A/art? art/runtime/stack.cc:322] Expected: java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) Found: java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader)
    03-19 21:10:29.524  31799-31809/com.learn.btnine.btbnine A/art? art/runtime/stack.cc:322] Expected: java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) Found: java.lang.Class java.lang.Class.classForName(java.lang.String, boolean, java.lang.ClassLoader)
    03-19 21:10:29.524  31799-31809/com.learn.btnine.btbnine A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] Runtime aborting --- recursively, so no thread-specific detail!
    03-19 21:10:29.524  31799-31809/com.learn.btnine.btbnine A/art? art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]
    03-19 21:10:29.524  31799-31809/com.learn.btnine.btbnine A/libc? Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00007c37 (code=-6), thread 31809 (JDWP)
```

Comment: Does it work if you run on Dalvik instead of ART?

Comment: No, I tried that too.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem right now, it is working as expected when running, but it crashes with this same error message when trying to debug my app. Have you find a solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same thing: ClassLoader error followed by SIGABRT, but only when running the debugger.

For me, switching from ART to Dalvik fixed it.