# Can we use Dalvik with Tango

Tags: google-project-tango

So I ran into the dreaded 'unfortunately....has stopped working' issue where art loads 2 classes and the debugger promptly tanks out - [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521636/cannot-debug-fatal-signal-6-sigabrt-at-0x00007c37-code-6)

So, in utter desperation, I switched from ART to Dalvik, half dreading a long session with ADB if the tablet got sour about the switch.  Seemed to work.  Tango works, albeit with a whole new set of head scratchers (flakier about getting XyzIj, flash is running, surface binding working, hell I can see the camera flashes in the surface showing the camera view - and if I try again and again, I do get tango point data :-)

Can I assume all the tango issues are of my own doing and keep using Dalvik, or must I switch back to ART and try to do all of my debugging through logcat ?

Comment: What version of Android studio you are using? The debug logger crash looks more like a android studio issue rather than Tango. The link you sent it using 0.5.1, which is quite old.

Comment: 1.0.2, updating on stable channel - link I sent was not me, I just get the same damn error - interestingly enough, after switching from ART to Dalvik, and then back to ART, with all the program optimization that goes on, the problem seems to have subsided - the only thing I'm reasonably certain of right now is that it's a bad idea to debug the tango tablet through a usb hub, or at least my hub(which has never had an issue and debugging tango through it makes other devices act weird ... go figure)  I think its all an ART issue, but the general recommendation is switch to Dalvik and we can't :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in title: Can we use Dalvik with Tango?

You should always use ART instead of Delvik on Tango, Delvik will work but **NOT** stable on Tango device, it might cause the issue you experienced like depth out-of-sync.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here,

What helps is switching to Dalvik for debugging non tango-related issues, but this really slows development process down, as all apps have to be optimized for each switch between debugging and testing session.